# How to concatenate coma delimited strings without duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to strings `@x = "a,b,c,d,e,f" @y="d,e,f,g,h"`.

How to remove duplicates from both strings so the so the `@z="a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h"` is concatenated but without duplicates?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products have their own versions of string functions.)

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Comment: @Mureinik Sorry forgot the correct tag.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, forgot to add correct tag.

Comment: If your SQL Server is recent enough to have `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG`, easy peasy. Otherwise, an exercise in suffering and kludges and an excellent reason to do this client-side, or to store the data with normalization in the first place.

Comment: For sql 2017 or more `declare @x varchar(max) = 'a,b,c,d,e,f',@y varchar(max)= 'd,e,f,g,h'

;with cte
as
(
select  value  from string_split(@x,',')
union 
select  value  from string_split(@y,',')
)
select string_Agg(value,',') from cte`

Answer (score 0):

You would split them apart then reaggregate:

```
select @z = string_agg(xy.value, ',') within group (order by xy.value) 
from (select sx.value
      from string_split(@x) sx
      union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select sy.value
      from string_split(@y) sy
     ) xy;
```

Comment: I tried that `declare @x varchar(max) = 'a' ,@y varchar(max)= 'a,b,c'  ;
select @z = string_agg(xy.value order by xy.value) 
from (select sx.value
      from string_split(@x) sx
      union  
      select sy.value
      from string_split(@y) sy
     ) xy;` and I am getting: `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.
Msg 313, Level 16, State 3, Line 5
An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function string_split.
`

Comment: `string_agg(xy.value, ',') within group (order by xy.value)` (because of course that has its own separate little syntax) and `string_split(@x, ',')`.